# How to get the current pattern-object contents of a canvas-context (2D)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, 2d

(Using Firefox32, and Win7. But in other browsers I need it to work, too.)

I can't find a command to retrieve the content of the pattern-object that I set on the 2D-context.

Is there no direct way to get the value array and the width and height?

And if there is really no direct way, is there a workaround?

I could just use fillRect with the pattern on a hidden canvas and then reading out the canvas. But then, how to get the correct height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pattern properties

The only method exposed on the [`CanvasPattern`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#2dcontext) object is to handle transformations:

```
interface CanvasPattern {
  // opaque object
  void setTransform(SVGMatrix transform);
};
```

This means all other properties has to be tracked externally.

## Workaround 1 - manually keep track of properties

The workaround is to read the width and height from the image you used for the pattern, as well as mode and optionally transforms.

Just keep a reference to them for later:

```
var img = ...;                                      // image source
var patternMode = "repeat";                         // store repeat mode
var patternWidth = img.naturalWidth;                // width and height of image
var patternHeight = img.naturalHeight;              // = width and height of pattern

var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, patternMode);  // use to create pattern
```

## Workaround 2 - create a custom object

You can create a custom object which wraps up the pattern creation process and exposes methods that can hold width, height etc.

#### Example

An object could look like this:

```
function PatternExt(ctx, image, mode) {

    var ptn = ctx.createPattern(image, mode || "repeat");

    this.setTransform = ptn.setTransform ? ptn.setTransform.bind(ptn) : null;
    this.width = image.naturalWidth;
    this.height = image.naturalHeight;
    this.image = image;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.pattern = ptn;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of creating an instance almost the same way as with `createPattern()`:

```
var p = new PatternExt(ctx, img, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = p.pattern;
```

To read information do:

```
var w = p.width;
var h = p.height;
...
```

Rename/extend as you want/need.

## Demo for custom object

```js
// load an image for pattern
var img = new Image();
img.onload = demo;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/HF5eJZS.gif";

function demo() {
    var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"), p;

    // create a pattern instance
    p = new PatternExt(ctx, img, "repeat");
    
    // use as fill-style
    ctx.fillStyle = p.pattern;                  
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);

    // show some properties
    ctx.font = "24px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillText([p.width, p.height, p.mode].join(), 10, 30);
}

function PatternExt(ctx, image, mode) {
    var ptn = ctx.createPattern(image, mode || "repeat");
    this.setTransform = ptn.setTransform ? ptn.setTransform.bind(ptn) : null;
    this.width = image.naturalWidth;
    this.height = image.naturalHeight;
    this.image = image;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.pattern = ptn;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your desired pattern is currently used as the fillStyle, then you can fetch it by fetching the fillStyle:

```
myPattern=context.fillStyle;
```

Otherwise you can't fetch your pattern object because the context keeps any pattern objects you've created as private properties.

So typically you keep a reference to your pattern until it's not needed anymore.

If you also need the original imageObject used to create your pattern then you typically save a reference to that image also.

```
// create an imageObject for use in your pattern
var myImageObject=new Image();
myImageObject.onload=start;      // call start() when myImageObject is fully loaded
myImageObject.src="";

function start(){

    // myImageObject has now been fully loaded so
    // create your pattern and keep a reference to it
    var myPattern = context.createPattern(myImageObject, 'repeat');

}

... and later when you need the pattern ...

// use your pattern object reference to apply the pattern as a fillStyle
context.fillStyle = myPattern;

... and later if you need the original image object

// get the original image object's size
var imgWidth=myImageObject.width;
var imgHeight=myImageObject.height;

// draw the original image object to the context -- or whatever you need it for
context.drawImage(myImageObject,50,50);
```